# How do I reference to a List<> object that was created in a class?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, parameter-passing

I have 2 separate files in my Flutter application, main.dart and class1.dart

class1.dart is defined in my models/ folder

I am trying to access the List that I created from the SampleWidget class but I am unsure how to do this. IntelliSense wasn't able to find the List I had made from the instance object of SampleWidget.

What I'm trying to achieve is:

`AssetImage(SampleWidget.listSampleWidget[0].foo)`

**class1.dart**

```
class SampleWidget {
  final String foo;
  final int bar;

  SampleWidget({this.foo, this.bar});
}

List<SampleWidget> listSampleWidget = [
  SampleWidget(
    foo: 'assets/001.png',
    bar: 420,
  ),
];
```

main.dart is just the default boilerplate code when creating a new Flutter application,

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sandbox1/models/class1.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final extSampleClass = SampleWidget();
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {

      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(

        child: Column(

          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
            //AssetImage(<pass SampleWidget foo parameter from the List here>),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

How do I reference to the List from the class here? Is something like this even doable or is there a different approach?

Comment: Your list is created outside class, you can use it directly, without class name. or may create it with static type in the class, to access the way you want rn.

Comment: So instead I should do this?
`listSampleWidget[0].foo` to get the String object that contain the asset, right? I tried that but it returned me an error  "The element type 'AssetImage' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget' "

Comment: I think the problem is me using AssetImage as a normal widget, documentation stated AssetImage has to be used under the image: only

Comment: Right.. But AssetImage class is not a widget, its a ImageProvider. You should use Image.asset() to display images as a widget

Comment: what @SahdeepSingh mentioned worked. Using `Image.asset(listSampleWidget[0].foo)` I was able to get the image I store in the assets/ folder. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AssetImage()` cannot be used as a standalone widget. Using `Image.asset()` worked. I can call the List object directly without having to reference the class apparently.

So the code will look something like:

```
Image.asset(listSampleWidget[0].foo)
```

And I got the picture on my test device!